# Getting javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I'm developing a JSF 2.2 software and I'm using EL expressions like that:

```
#{(l.fucionality != '47') && (l.funcionality != '48')}
```

On my own environment this works fine. The problem is when I put the web archive in an other server. Even running the same version of JDK and Tomcat, when I try to reach the page that uses EL Expressions as listed above I get this error:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException.

Comment: The answer is in the stack trace. If you can't interpret the stack trace, please include the stack trace in the question (in code block) so that we can translate it in layman's terms.